# Creating a view with multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, view

I am trying to create a view with 5 tables however I am having issues when trying to join the last two tables together.

Here is my current MySQL query:

```
CREATE VIEW s_view AS
    SELECT AC.id, A.id AS account_id, A.name, A.description, A.industry, A.phone_fax, A.phone_office, A.shipping_address_street, A.shipping_address_city, A.shipping_address_state, A.shipping_address_postalcode, A.shipping_address_country, C.id AS contact_id, C.first_name, C.last_name, C.title, C.department, C.phone_home, C.phone_mobile, C.phone_work, C.primary_address_street, C.primary_address_city, C.primary_address_state, C.primary_address_postalcode, C.primary_address_country, EA.Email_address
    FROM ACCOUNTS A
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS_CONTACTS AS AC ON A.id = AC.account_id 
    INNER JOIN CONTACTS AS C ON C.id = AC.contact_id 
    INNER JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER ON ER.bean_id = A.id
    INNER JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA ON ER.email_address_id = EA.id
```

And my tables are set up in the following way:

ACCOUNTS (id, first_name, last_name, etc.)

CONTACTS (id, name, etc.)

ACCOUNT_CONTACTS (id, account_id, contact_id)

EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL (id, bean_id (same as account_id / contact_id), email_address_id)

EMAIL_ADDRESSES (email_address_id, email_address)

The issue I am having is that the EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL table has a bean_id that can reference either an account_id or a contact_id. Therefore when I join the tables it only returns the accounts email address however i want it to return both the accounts email address and the contacts email address?

I have a feeling it is an issue with the way i am joining the tables but i am unsure as how to move forward?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know whether bean_id references the account_id or the contact_id? Is there another field which specifies or is it just the existence or lack thereof?

Comment: @PeterBowers there is also another field within that table: bean_module that specifies if it is an account or a contact. I'm assuming when writing my select i would need two email fields one for the account & one for the contact, im just not sure how to do that :S

Comment: will there always be an accounts email address and a contacts email address? or can one or both be null?

Comment: @BK435 these fields can be null

Comment: Can you confirm if your existing query (strip off the "CREATE VIEW" stuff at the top) generates rows in your system as it stands? Since all I've added at this point is `LEFT JOIN` to that (and actually changed one of your `INNER JOIN` into a `LEFT`) my query should be returning potentially MORE rows and never less...

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the last two joins also had a left join, once I changed that it worked perfectly ! Thank you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set up 2 separate aliases for the EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL table and reference it appropriately (because of your structure you have to add another aliased version of email_address as well):

```
CREATE VIEW s_view AS
    SELECT AC.id, A.id AS account_id, A.name, A.description, A.industry, 
        A.phone_fax, A.phone_office, A.shipping_address_street, 
        A.shipping_address_city, A.shipping_address_state, 
        A.shipping_address_postalcode, A.shipping_address_country, 
        C.id AS contact_id, C.first_name, C.last_name, C.title, 
        C.department, C.phone_home, C.phone_mobile, C.phone_work, 
        C.primary_address_street, C.primary_address_city, 
        C.primary_address_state, C.primary_address_postalcode, 
        C.primary_address_country, 
        EA.Email_address, 
        EA_C.Email_address AS Email_address_c
    FROM ACCOUNTS A
    INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS_CONTACTS AS AC ON A.id = AC.contact_id 
    INNER JOIN CONTACTS AS C ON C.id = AC.account_id 
    LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER ON ER.bean_id = AC.id
        AND ER.bean_module = 'accounts'
    LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDR_BEAN_REL AS ER_C ON ER.bean_id = C.id
        AND ER_C.bean_module = 'contacts'
    LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA ON ER.email_address_id = EA.id
    LEFT JOIN EMAIL_ADDRESSES AS EA_C ON ER_C.email_address_id = EA_C.id
```

---

### EDIT

Since you do not necessarily have a row for accounts or for contacts (if I understand correctly from the comments above - thanks, @BK435) it is now set up as a LEFT JOIN. I've also added the specifying of the `bean_module` column (although I'm not sure what code you are using for that).

Comment: This returns zero results :(

Comment: Sorry - I copy/pasted the final line and forgot to rename the alias for the final column name. Try it again now.

Comment: @Peter, based on OP response, if the fields for email address for both contact and account can be null, wouldn't you need to left join on Email_Addresses to produce results and not inner join??

Comment: sorry i had an error in my original post, its fixed now. However even after fixing my error and using your query it still returns zero results

Comment: I've made a couple edits trying to keep up with how the question is changing. Now it allows for non-existent email addresses. I also fixed another couple aliases.

Comment: Thank you this works ! However i currently have two contact records one with an email and one without, how can i retrieve both despite one having  a value of null for their email? Wouldn't i need an outer left join ?

Comment: "INNER" and "OUTER" are syntactical fluff, as I understand it. Saying `INNER JOIN` is the same as saying `JOIN`. Saying `LEFT JOIN` is the same as saying `OUTER LEFT JOIN`. I'm not 100% sure on this, but about 98%.

Comment: @PeterBowers, I usually use a subselect to grab just that value as another column in the query or create a completely separate view to join that is populated only with, in this case, an id and contact email...Next time I will try using this alias method...Thanks +1